# Join with all values match in second table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have 3 tables Users, UserRoles, Roles.
I'm trying to select users who has exact roles.

```
SELECT *
FROM Users
LEFT JOIN UserRoles ON UserRoles.UserId = Users.UserId
LEFT JOIN Roles ON Roles.RoleId = UserRoles.RoleId
WHERE Roles.RoleId IN (1,2)
```

I'm getting valid result but, I get users who are also only in RoleId = 1 or only in RoleId = 2.

How can I select only users who contains 2 (or more) exact roles?

Comment: What details of those users are you wanting? I assume you don't really you want `SELECT *`.

Comment: @Larnu Users.UserId for example

Comment: LEFT JOIN is unuseful as you've write your query

Comment: @JoeTaras I understand, but i'm not very good with SQL so can you elaborate or give me a hint? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be sure both roles exist, you can test for both roles e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM Users U
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM UserRoles UR
  INNER JOIN Roles R ON R.RoleId = UR.RoleId
  WHERE UR.UserId = U.UserId and R.RoleId = 1
)
AND EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM UserRoles UR
  INNER JOIN Roles R ON R.RoleId = UR.RoleId
  WHERE UR.UserId = U.UserId and R.RoleId = 2
);
```

Note the use of aliases for clarity. And `inner join`'s since there shouldn't be a null case.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the User ID of users that have 2, or more, roles, use a `HAVING`:

```sql
SELECT U.UserID
FROM dbo.Users U
     JOIN dbo.UserRoles UR ON U.UserID = UR.UserID
     JOIN dbo.Roles R ON UR.RoleID = R.RoleID
GROUP BY U.UserID
HAVING COUNT(R.RoleID) >= 2;
```

If you want to them have specific roles you just add the `WHERE` to limit them; like you have in your attempt. If you're looking for 3 specific roles, just ensure you change the `HAVING` to `>=3` (or the appropriate number).

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytical function as follows:

```
select * from
(SELECT u.*, count(distinct Roles.RoleId) over (partition by Users.UserId) as cnt
FROM Users
LEFT JOIN UserRoles ON UserRoles.UserId = Users.UserId
LEFT JOIN Roles ON Roles.RoleId = UserRoles.RoleId
WHERE Roles.RoleId IN (1,2) ) t
where cnt = 2
```